# Testing incrementation in Foundry

Tags: solidity, nft, testing, foundry

Currently testing my smart contract using Foundry and I believe it is going pretty well. However, I have some incrementation going on in my smart contract program which is an NFT Marketplace and I am not sure how to test incrementation in Foundry. Do you guys have any tips?

I cannot seem to find a direct answer in Google so I thought I might as well come here to ask. I posted my code down below. If you have any constructive criticism regarding my work feel free to say! I am always looking to learn and improve! Thank you!

[image]

Here is my contract itself. This is the buy function.

[image]